# can't view or change keyboard options

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, cinnamon, xkb

I cannot view or change the keyboard layout options anymore on Linux Mint. Does anyone know how I could fix this? I am afraid, resetting the options might not solve the problem and then I'd lose all my settings and couldn't restore them.

Does anyone know, where the settings are stored? (And maybe the name of the program in cinnamon?)

[image: Keyboard options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error in the evdev.xml file. I think this may be connected to accidental inserts that annoyingly sometimes happen when I click on the touchpad.